# How to view readable version of session data object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the domain name from the session data object, but the object is massive and very dense.

Sample of data

```
#<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x007f982c42b988 @by=#
<ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore:0x007f982e03d798 @app=#
<ActionDispatch::Flash:0x007f982e03d7e8 @app=#
<ActionDispatch::ParamsParser:0x007f982e03d9a0 @app=#
<Rack::Head:0x007f982e03d9f0 @app=#<Rack::ConditionalGet:0x007f982e03da40 
@app=#<Rack::ETag:0x007f982e03da68 @app=#<OmniAuth::Builder:0x007f982e03e4b8 
@options=nil, @warmup=nil, @run=#
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f982c4325f8>, @map=nil, @use=[#
<Proc:0x007f982e03db30@/REMOVED/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-
1.6.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:86>]>, @cache_control="max-age=0, private, must-
revalidate", @no_cache_control="no-cache">>>, @parsers={#
<Mime::Type:0x007f982dae3270 @synonyms=["text/x-json", 
"application/jsonrequest"], @symbol=:json, @string="application/json", 
@hash=-2179284299704414862>=>:json}>>, @default_options={:path=>"/", 
:domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, 
:defer=>false, :renew=>false}, @key="_faq-app_session", @cookie_only=true>, 
@env={"SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"thin 1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin",
```

It goes on like this for several pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing the structure of an arbitrary object is not something that is encouraged by OOP principles: objects hide things that should be irrelevant outside them. Also, there might be more data than would be feasible to read all at once. To explore random objects, the best way might be `pry` gem, which allows you to inspect objects in console. If really needed, one can rather easily create a function that would recurse over all of object's `instance_variables` and print them all.

However, the generic approach is probably not needed here. This seems to be an `ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options` object. It has a `#to_hash` method, and hashes can be pretty-printed:

```
require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(session_options.to_hash)
```

or if you don't need it in a standard format,

```
require 'pp'
pp session_options.to_hash
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll give this a shot in my rails application